# Twilio Fax API Unknown Domain Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio

So attempting to integrate Twilio fax into my Codeigniter application I keep getting the error: "**Unknown domain fax**" thrown from the Twilio SDK. The example below is pretty much exactly what they tell you to do in their own example. So I am not sure what the underlying issue is. Worse off I can't find anything in there documents which even gives a hint to what that may mean. Hoping someone here can shed some light on the subject.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

// Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php/Twilio/autoload.php';
// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class Twilio {
    public function icecream () {
        // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
        $sid = "omitted";
        $token = "omitted";
        $client = new Client($sid, $token);

        $options = array(
            "from" => "+15555555555"
        );
        $fax = $client->fax->v1->faxes->create(
            "+15555555555",
            "https://www.twilio.com/docs/documents/25/justthefaxmaam.pdf",
            $options
        );

        echo $fax->sid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but a quick load of the PDF url returns a 404 page.

Comment: Oddly enough, that file and url was working last i checked, however.. in light of that, I put a pdf on my server and point to it from the script now. Same error though as assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My guess is that you are using the production PHP library with the [Fax API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/rest/faxes). The latest version of which is 5.10.0.

Our beta and preview products are not released as part of the main library as they may change more frequently than the rest of the library. Instead they are released as part of an `alpha` release of the library. You can [read more on this versioning strategy](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/VERSIONS.md#edge-features-alpha-branch).

So, I recommend you install 5.10.0-alpha1 and try again. You should find the fax API works just fine then.

Comment: This is correct I found that out later, also inadvertantly I found out in this specific instance I could not use the trial account to test with to see if it was a viable solution for my needs. In order for me to test, I needed to upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: Ah, I did not know you needed a paid account for fax. Thanks. As the answer was correct, do you mind marking it as such, so that anyone else who has this problem can tell easily. Thanks!

Comment: This is a mess to manage since we don't want alpha versions of other Twilio services but do want to put the beta fax into production.

Comment: Using the alpha library doesn't mean you use any other Twilio services, it just includes the code to call them. The general availability services of Twilio in the alpha libraries aren't different from the regular version of the library. How are you managing this?